# Number of ways to enter 1,2,3,4,5,6 on the spots marked on three intersecting circles and have the sums of 14

Tags: combinations, gre-exam

[image]

How to solve it , i applied so many method but i could not find right answer,
suggest me some method
combination question gre 44

Comment: like a,b,c,d are on the circumference of one circle and same way d e b f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You can easily form a matrix from your set of equations. You should eventually find that $a+c=e+f=b+d=7$. The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: I m thinking by matrix  it will take more time ,i have to solve this question with in 2 min

Comment: This matrix should be easily solved in under 30 seconds by anyone practicing for the GRE.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;a+c=A$, $\;b+d=B$, $\;e+f=C$.

You have the equations

$$
A+B=B+C=C+A=14\\
A+B+C=21
$$

So $\;A=B=C=7$, and that means $\;a+c=e+f=b+d=7$.

That means you have only to decide which variables are $1,2,3$, and the others are set.